# joining 2 table with sum in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to joining 2 table from MYSQL in PHP With SUM. But when I get result it shows multiply result. I don't know what's wrong in my script. Please help. My script shown bellow with table:

```
  table1: sale
  id    party    amount
  1     Topu     1000
  2     Rashed   2000
  3     Topu     5000 
  4     Topu     7000
  5     Rashed   5000

  table2: party_ledger

  id    party    payment_amount
  1     Topu          2000
  2     Rashed        7000
  3     Topu          4000 
  4     Topu          5000
  5     Rashed        4000

  <?php
  $sql= "SELECT sale.party, party_ledger.party, SUM(sale.amount) AS amount,
  SUM(party_ledger.payment_amount) AS pamount FROM sale
  INNER JOIN party_ledger ON sale.party=party_ledger.party
  GROUP BY sale.party,party_ledger.party";

  $result = $cn->query($sql);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

  <tr style="font-size: 10px">

  <td><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></td>

  <td><?php echo $row['pamount']; ?></td>

  </tr>

  <?php   }
  $cn->close(); ?>
```

unfortunately I am getting wrong result. Please Help.

Comment: what's with the down vote?. the query that i've made for you will surely work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql= "SELECT sale.party, party_ledger.party, SUM(sale.amount) AS amount,
      SUM(party_ledger.payment_amount) AS pamount FROM (select party,sum(amount) as amount from sale group by party) sale
      INNER JOIN (select party,sum(payment_amount) as payment_amount from party_ledger group by party) party_ledger ON sale.party=party_ledger.party GROUP BY sale.party,party_ledger.party";
```

You can try the above query

Comment: If it is correct , please click on Right check  button.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it'll work... But I guess it'll give you an idea.. you need to query your desired result first on the first table and do the same on the second after that you can join both of them.

`SELECT SUM(tbl_sale.total_amt) as sale_total, SUM(tbl_pt_ledger.ledger_total_amt) as ledger_total FROM
(SELECT party, SUM(amount) as total_amt FROM sale GROUP BY party) tbl_sale
INNER JOIN
(SELECT party, SUM(payment_amount) as ledger_total_amt FROM party_ledger GROUP BY party) tbl_pt_ledger
ON tbl_sale.party = tbl_pt_ledger.party`

Comment: please note that result should be group by party

Comment: Its also work but it gives the total result not party wise. Thanks @3113490

Comment: @VikasUmrao sorry guys.... I thought it just might help with you..  sorry since I wasn't on my laptop when I was doing that.. so, I wasn't able to test it out..